# Computer doesn't turn on with new RAM

Tags: memory, motherboard, upgrade

I bought new RAM the other day to try and upgrade my system.

I have 8GB (2x4GB) of Corsair Vengeance LPX DDR4 2400Mhz (CMK16GX4M4A2400C14) [CMK8GX4M2A2400C14](https://www.corsair.com/us/en/Categories/Products/Memory/VENGEANCE-LPX/p/CMK8GX4M2A2400C14)

I tried to upgrade it with 32GB (2x16GB) GSkill RipJaws DDR4 3200Mhz [F4-3200C16D-32GVK](https://www.gskill.com/product/165/184/1536110922/F4-3200C16D-32GVK-Overview)

My motherboard is a [Gigabyte GA-X99-UD4](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-X99-UD4-rev-10) which says it supports 64GB of RAM. (I know it's a shitty motherboard but it's what came with the computer).

When I put the new GSkill RAM in the computer will attempt to start but then shut off. If I put the old Corsair RAM back it the computer starts up again.

I've tried each of the RAM sticks in each of the RAM slots individually to see if one of the sticks was bad, but no luck. I've made sure they're seated properly as well.

Everything I've read says these should be compatible but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm not sure if I just got duds for RAM or if the problem is with the motherboard, I suspect it's with the motherboard given the reviews on the RAM.

Answer (score 1):

According to your
[motherboard manual](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-x99-ud4_e.pdf),
the memory specification is:

[image]

The RAM you bought is 3200 MHz, while the maximum for the motherboard is
2133 Mhz.

I have also consulted the excellent Crucial website for
[GA-X99-UD4 Compatible upgrades](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/gigabyte/ga-x99-ud4)
and I note that it never recommends RAM sticks of more than 8 GB each.
Its largest kits are for 2 x 8GB.
This might be another reason that your RAM of 16 GB sticks might be unsuitable.

To be sure of the RAM you buy, I suggest running the
[Crucial Scan computer utility](https://www.crucial.com/)
which does an excellent job of analyzing your hardware.
Their prices are also very competitive and their products are guaranteed compatible.

An important note is the correct placing of the RAM sticks.
The manual lists these RAM configurations:

[image]

Comment: That's a very comprehensive answer. The gigabyte website says it should support speeds up to 3333mhz. https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-X99-UD4-rev-10#ov. But it do think the RAM larger than 8 GB could be the problem. I'll buy smaller RAM and try again. Thanks.

Comment: I believe you're both partially right - XMP is *technically* OC, so for whatever reason Gigabyte must have decided to just not list anything faster than 2133 in the manual. Also @Dan.T do you have XMP enabled? If you do and it works, this shows that 2133 is _not_ the maximum.

Comment: I don't know if I have XMP enabled but the original RAM they came with the computer was 2400 Mhz

Comment: So I bought some Crucial Ballistix 3200 MHz DDR4 DRAM Desktop Gaming Memory Kit 16GB (8GBx2) CL16 BL2K8G32C16U4B (Black) (which was on the list of acceptable RAM) but same issue. Computer doesn't turn on

Comment: Did you run the Crucial Scanner?

Comment: FWIW, I'm also trying to upgrade this mobo from 32GB to 64GB, I also got officially supported modules, but I never got it working. It just shuts off.

Answer (score 0):

Update the BIOS and restart. I do not think BIOS is the solution in these cases, but update it and try.

Then get the computer manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App on a bootable USB key. Boot with this and test the hardware.

If all above is well and the old memory works, return the new memory for replacement or refund (to get different memory).

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I'm looking at from the supported memory list, the RAM you have installed into is not supported.

I don't think these lists are always fully comprehensive, but this is a longer list than I've seen for most. They tested a lot of different RAM modules.

`F4-3200C` is not even listed for the [Haswell CPU list](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Memory/mb_memory_x99-haswell-e_180221.pdf).

`F4-3200C` is listed in the [Broadwell CPU list](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Memory/mb_memory_x99-broadwell-e_180221.pdf), but `F4-3200C16**D**` is **not** listed. The only supported 32 GB variant for `F4-3200C` that is listed for Broadwell is `F4-3200C16**Q**-32GVK`

Corsair `CMK16GX4M4A2400C14` is listed as supported on **both** lists.

I would try to get one that is on the list, that matches your desired needs.

Comment: `F4-3200C16Q-64GVK` is a quad equivalent of OP's `F4-3200C16D-32GVK`, so I dare say their G.Skill kit will work with a Broadwell CPU. QVLs are not strictly _required_ and it's quite common to find the same stick but in a larger kit (i.e. quad kit vs dual kit, like here). While the `F4-3200C16**Q**-32GVK` you mention is a 4x8 kit which is vastly different than OP's